# Ao salvar arquivo pdf os espaços, são substituídos por "%20" (sem as aspas)

Tags: c#

Estou usando interop para criar um documento word e no final salvá-lo em PDF, tudo ocorre bem exceto o nome do arquivo, e usei este caminho para salvá-lo.

```
var NovoDocumento = "C:/Users/Bird/Desktop/PTD´S/" + tbNomeProf.Text + " - " + tbMateria.Text  + ".pdf";
```

Tudo ocorre bem exceto pelo fato dos espaços serem substituídos por %20

O nome do arquivo era pra estar da seguinte forma

> ```
> Leandro Ferro -  Sistema de Tratamento de Água e Resíduos.pdf
> ```

mas está saindo assim

> ```
> Leandro%20Ferro%20-%20%20Sistema%20de%20Tratamento%20de%20Água%20e%20Resíduos.pdf
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Tenta colocar mais uma aspas duplas assim:

```
var NovoDocumento = "C:/Users/Bird/Desktop/PTD´S/"" + tbNomeProf.Text + " - "" + tbMateria.Text  + ".pdf";
```

fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851588/asp-net-download-file-when-file-name-contain-spaces

Comment: Barra invertida, não? Também tem o fato de que o AP não falou nada de download, já que sua fonte é específica sobre fazer downloads

Comment: Acho que a barra invertida deve funcionar, realmente